# Defining input element properties as defineObject javascript method

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I define properties such as `placeholder` or `pattern` with:

```
Object.defineProperty(inputProto, 'placeholder', {value: 20, writable: true});
```

It works, but when I search on the `HTML`, it says `undefined`.

How can I define a `Web Component` property in `JavaScript` with `htmlElements`? I don't want to set them in the `HTML`.

**Code:**

```
var inputProto = Object.create(HTMLInputElement.prototype);
//funciones del js API (prototype del componnente)   
inputProto.onClear = function() {
    this.value = "";
    this.style.position = "static";
    this.placeholder = "New Text";
}

inputProto.setPos = function(x, y) {
    this.style.top = x + "px";
    this.style.left = y + "px";
    this.style.position = "relative";
}

inputProto.setDimensions = function(width, height) {
    this.style.width = width + "px";
    this.style.height = height + "px";
}

inputProto.caps = function(input) {
    input = this.value;
    var regEx = /[A-Z]/;
    var match = regEx.test(input);
    if (match) {
        alert("Valid")
    } else {
        alert("Not valid")
    }
}

inputProto.lowerCaps = function(input) {
    input = this.value;
    var regEx = /[^A-Z]/;
    var match = regEx.test(input);
    if (match) {
        alert("Valid")
    } else {
        alert("Not valid")
    }
}

var EgComponent = document.registerElement('eg-input', {
    prototype: inputProto,
    extends: 'input'
});

var egcomp = new EgComponent();
//function de componente ya creado en el DOM
function test() {
    egcomp.onClear();
    egcomp.setDimensions(250, 15);
}

function test1() {
    egcomp.setDimensions(350, 15);
}

function test2() {
    egcomp.caps();
}

function test3() {
    egcomp.lowerCaps();
}

function test4() {
    egcomp.setPos(30, 580);
}
//metiendo el componente al html desde el dom
document.body.appendChild(egcomp);
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty interesting question @EduardoGonzalez. Upvoted! You can view my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47542945/6313073).

Comment: excelent, it did what i wanted to, thanks to translating the code to the new way to type it, im starting to learn js well, thanks

Comment: You're welcome @EduardoGonzalez. I'm glad I could help! Please, be sure to give an upvote and accept my answer, if it helped you, so that others who stumble upon it in the future may be helped as well 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the properties you set using `Object.defineProperty` is `undefined`, because you set them on the prototype instead of an `EgComponent` instance:

```
/* That's what you do. */
Object.defineProperty(inputProto, "placeholder", {value: 20, writable: true});
```

Properties such as `value`, `pattern` and `placeholder` are instance-specific rather than prototype-specific, so in order to actually set those properties for an instance of `EgComponent`, you must use `defineProperty` on `egcomp` rather than `inputProto`:

```
/* That's what you should do to set the property. */
Object.defineProperty(egcomp, "placeholder", {value: 20, writable: true});
```

If you define the property as shown above, the property will be set  for `egcomp` and you can see that it is `20`, if you type `egcomp.placeholder;` in the console. However, you can easily notice that, even though the `placeholder` property for `egcomp` is set, the `HTML` attribute has not been set. You can verify that if you type `egcomp.getAttribute("placeholder");` in the console. To solve that problem, you can ditch `Object.defineProperty` and set the property the old-fashioned way:

```
/* That's what you should do to set the property and HTML attribute. */
egcomp.placeholder = 20;
```

Check out the following snippet to see how it works.

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ---------- The EgComponent class ---------- */
;(function () {
  /* Create a new object from the prototype of HTMLInputElement. */
  var inputProto = Object.create(HTMLInputElement.prototype);

  /* Define some basic methods for the prototype of the component */
  Object.defineProperties(inputProto, {
    /* The function that clears a component instance. */
    onClear: {
      value: function() {
        this.value = "";
        this.style.position = "static";
        this.placeholder = "New Text";
      }
    },

    /* The function that sets the position of a component instance. */
    setPos: {
      value: function(x, y) {
        this.style.top = x + "px";
        this.style.left = y + "px";
        this.style.position = "relative";
      }
    },

    /* The function that sets the dimensions of a component instance. */
    setDimensions: {
      value: function(width, height) {
        this.style.width = width + "px";
        this.style.height = height + "px";
      }
    },

    /* The function that returns if the value of a component instance is uppercase. */
    caps: {
      value: function(input) {
        alert(/[A-Z]/.test(this.value) ? "Valid" : "Not Valid");
      }
    },

    /* The function that returns if the value of a component instance is lowercase. */
    lowerCaps: {
      value: function(input) {
        alert(/[a-z]/.test(this.value) ? "Valid" : "Not Valid");
      }
    },
  });

  /* Register the EgComponent in the browser. */
  window.EgComponent = document.registerElement("eg-input", {
    prototype: inputProto,
    extends: "input"
  });
})();



/* ---------- Instantiating an EgComponent ---------- */

/* Create a new instance of EgComponent. */
var egcomp = new EgComponent();

/* Set the 'placeholder' property. */
egcomp.placeholder = 20;

/* Set the 'pattern' property. */
egcomp.pattern = /[a-z]/;

/* Insert the component into the body of the document. */
document.body.appendChild(egcomp);

/* Log the component to the console. */
console.log(egcomp);
```